# Conjugates of a cycle $\sigma$ in $S_n$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

I'm trying to study the different cycle types and their conjugates in a symmetric group $S_n$.

For more of a concrete example, suppose we are given a cycle $\sigma \in S_5$.
My questions are:

How to determine what elements are conjugate to $\sigma$,

how many elements are of the same cycle type as $\sigma$,

lastly how to determine what the elements of the centralizer $C_G(\sigma)$ are.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be a cycle of order $m$ in $S_n$

1. The elements that are conjugate to $\sigma$ are also cycle of order $m$.
2. The number of elements that are of same cycle type of $\sigma$ is $(1/m)(n)(n-1)\dots(n-m+1)$
3. $|C_G(\sigma)|=(n-m)!m$

Comment: What if $\sigma = (12)(34)$, or any disjoint product of two cycles? Does the formula above still apply?

Comment: @user282639 No, those properties are only for cycle.

Comment: Then how would I go about determining the 3 things for a non r-cycle? i.e. $(12)(34), (123)(4657)$ etc...

Comment: Then the elements that are conjugate must have same cycle structure. For example the elements which are conjugate to $(12)(34)$ are $(13)(24),(14)(23)$

Comment: How can I determine how many elements have such cycle types?

Comment: @user282639 The number of  $\sigma\in S_n$ written in the form of disjoint cycle has $e_1$ cycle of length $1$, $e_2$ cycle of length 2,... $e_n$ cycle of length $n$, is $\frac{n}{1^{e_1}e_1!\dots n^{e_n}e_n!}$

Comment: Doesn't $(3,4)$ centralize  $(1,2)$?

Comment: @BogaertsMarc  You are right. I found my mistake